# sharepoint 2010 how to call multiple lists in tabbed interface

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have NEWS, EVENTS and other list items which i want to show in tabbed interface..and also want next and previous buttons to navigate list items on each tab. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Easytabs](http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx)

for the Tabs, the selection has to be made by Jquery and the client Object model by hand, I sugges

Lars